# Spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{6}]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

I'm trying to find the spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{6}]$.
For that, I wanted to look at it as a Localization of $A := \mathbb{Z}$ with respect to $S:=\{6\}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{6}] \cong S^{-1}A$.

I know that if $\mathfrak{p} \in spec\{A\}$ then $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a localization at $\mathfrak{p}$. But does it even tell me something about the spectrum?

Can someone tell me how one can calculate the spectrum of a localization?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is a ring, $S$ a multiplicative subset, and $S^{-1}A$ is the localization, then there is a bijection between the prime ideals of $S^{-1}A$ and the prime ideals of $A$ which don't intersect $S$.

Applying this to our case, the prime ideals of $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ are in bijection with prime ideals of $\Bbb Z$ which don't contain $6$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! that means $(2),(3)$ would not be in the spectrum but $(5)$? Or shouldn't any element in the prime ideal be divisible by 6? Because, if you say: prime ideals which don't contain 6, I have for example integer 30 in $(5)$ and $(6)$ but the element 6 itself is not in $(5)$.

Comment: A prime ideal $(p)$ in $\Bbb Z$ (this includes $p=0$) won't contain $6$ if and only if $p$ does not divide $6$.

Comment: So the spectrum would contain all prime ideal $p$ except the ones generated by 2 and 3. Thanks for the clarification!