# How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}[1/6]/(2020)\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, localization

Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$ and the module $(2020)\subset \mathbb{Z}$. In an algebra exercise from last year, it was asked how many elements the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[1/6]/(2020)\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$ has (where $(2020)\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$ is the submodule of $\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$ as expected). However, it seems to me that it is infinitely large, as $\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$ contains infinitely many elements (1,1/6,1/36,... as example, and I do not see how these elements differ in the quotient either). Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What can you use? Do you know localisations, e.g., [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614859/spectrum-of-mathbbz-frac16)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $$S^{-1}A/IS^{-1}A\simeq T^{-1}(A/I),$$ where $T$ is the image of $S$ in $A/I$.

In your case, the quotient ring is isomorphic to the ring of fractions of $\mathbb Z/2020\mathbb Z$ with respect to the multiplicative set $T$ of the powers of $\hat 6$. At its turn, this ring is isomorphic to a quotient ring of $\mathbb Z/2020\mathbb Z$. More precisely, the canonical map $\mathbb Z/2020\mathbb Z\to T^{-1}
(\mathbb Z/2020\mathbb Z)$ [is surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1822184/121097) and all you need is to find its kernel.

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you very much!